# The Unaverageables

Tags: code-golf

[Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/246025/average-ignorant-sets-of-integers).

Given a list of 3 or more positive integers, remove every number X for which there is another number Y in the list and the average of X and Y is also in the list. In other words, if X, Y, and the average of X and Y are all in the input, neither X nor Y should appear in the output.

Note: Pairs of numbers are not successively removed from the list, rather all at once. This avoids ambiguity. A pair of numbers whose average is in the list will be removed even if one or both of the numbers are already part of another such pair.

The average of two numbers is their sum divided by two.

Examples:

```
input => output
explanation

[1, 2, 3] => [2]
1 and 3 are removed because their average (2) is in the list.

[1, 2, 3, 4] => []
1 and 3 are removed because their average (2) is in the list,
2 and 4 are removed because their average (3) is in the list.

[1, 3, 4, 5] => [4]
1 and 5 are removed because their average (3) is in the list,
3 and 5 are removed because their average (4) is in the list.

[1, 5, 10, 20, 40] => [1, 5, 10, 20, 40]
No numbers are removed; No pair of numbers also has their average in the list.

[1, 5, 6, 10] => [1, 5, 6, 10]

[1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 52, 100, 200] => [10, 52, 200]

[1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34] => []
```

You may assume numbers are given in ascending order with no duplicates.

[code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) Shortest code wins.

Comment: why is 100 removed in `1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 52, 100, 200`?

Comment: @Jonah (100+4)/2 = 52

Comment: oh right, sorry, i was looking for 2 numbers that avg to 100...

Comment: Are we free to choose how to treat ambiguous cases? For example, for `[1, 2, 3, 5]` both of  the solutions `[2, 5]` and `[2,3]` are valid, right?

Comment: @cubiclettuce `[1, 2, 3, 5]` => `[2]`

Comment: Ah, now I got it, it's not about removing pairs successively, but about removing all such elements at once, thanks!

Comment: @cubiclettuce I'll make it more explicit in the spec :)

Comment: `NEITHER X nor Y should NOT appear in the output.` double negative so they should?

Comment: @T-Me fixed, typo

Comment: Can lists contain duplicates? e.g. is `[2, 2, 3] => [3]` a test case? This would break some solutions.

Comment: @GammaFunction you can assume the numbers are given with no duplicates in ascending order

Comment: So in `1,2,3,4,5` *all* numbers are removed, correct?

Comment: @RBarryYoung Correct, (1 5) and (2 4) both have their average (3), and (1 3) has their average (2)

Answer (score 8):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>9</s> 7 bytes

```
+HfḊʋÐḟ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/bI@3hjq5T3YcnPNwx///hdm/NyP//ow11FIx0FIxjdRRgTB0FEygPxNRRMIXyTHUUDA2ASoDYxAAhZgYSRtUOUWhqBKLBOlDlgZosgFJAlhHIEpNYAA)

```
     Ðḟ    Remove elements for which
+          that element plus each element of the list
 H         halved
   Ḋ       has more than one element
  f ʋ      after being filtered to only elements of the original list.
```

Answer (score 6):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>27 22 15</sup> 14 bytes

```
-.&,~:/~*+:-/]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY5BCsIwFET3PcWg0FqbpEmaiKQUioIrceG@K2kRNx5AyNXrb9IKdfFJ8v7MZF7jRmQDGocMDBKOhguc79fLyEXKvCv9vnC87MY8uZ0ELT9t7et261PW9cIHAXdtUfqkfzzfGKBQwcAm8a3RBKZRRZBl4G5BMBHuFINlUJJB0xiZz6I/vFIfps1KGEjUKAmrySV/e81QUUaMs3o6Q@5sMHPRWH5ddTHTF0fy0U0Tq8z4BQ)

Consider `1 3 4 5`.

- `+:-/]` We note that if `c = (a + b)/2`, then `2c - a = b`.  So we can double the input,
  and create a subtraction table between that doubled input and the original input:

  ```
  1 _1 _2 _3
  5  3  2  1
  7  5  4  3
  9  7  6  5
  ```

  Now any element in that table not on the diagonal is the `a` or `b` giving rise to
  a `c` in the original list, and thus invalid.
- `~:/~*` So zero out the diagonal:

  ```
  0 _1 _2 _3
  5  0  2  1
  7  5  0  3
  9  7  6  0
  ```
- `-.&,` Flatten, and then remove all the table elements from the original list:

  ```
  4
  ```

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), <s>48</s> 46 bytes

```
\(v)v[!v%in%combn(v,2)[,combn(v,2,mean)%in%v]]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuhY39WI0yjTLohXLVDPzVJPzc5PyNMp0jDSjdeBsndzUxDxNkHRZbCxU15c0jWQNQx0FIx0FY01NZQVbO4Voo1guJFEdBROYBFwcJKijYAoTN4FLmOooGBoA9QGxiQFMGl0cWbUZSAJVIVgI3QkQ_aZGIBpsEEITVBwohKYJaJYFUD2QZQRyM8IbEL8vWAChAQ)

Answer (score 6):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 17 bytes

```
{x^/x+(x-\:x)^'0}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJx1kd1uwyAMhe95CkeREsiPDDSZJrZMfY+mVLnJM3jK0mevoWnSrJuEMJzPHIwZ3UQeqZRU946Uz/UsxOim6Qdx6NDZYnDMvpXXM7oTnS80R24+08EPPnDGOyal6WpMc98baQvVU61ylf5mZW/Taod2pFbRcmF0zExXIuZD17v8fim6lb2aRpQl+GoaogvnMkr+OcdVFl8en2tcnsa9ktcuJVXUoQBbbPJD4B5uogzC0tlVpZKVE33QObZ7/PMLwICFwyNCE1ccoY2rFowGq6HRy/aNhS070NbyHJI2vYV3MAew7NQ8JbPlsTICRWVFokXViN0Fq/3dNBgmYdwA8bGKRg==)

Dang, [Jonah's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/248996/78410) translates very well to K.

```
{x^/x+(x-\:x)^'0}
      (x-\:x)      self difference table
             ^'0   remove zeros from each row
    x+             add i-th item of x to i-th row of matrix above
 x^/               seeded reduce: remove all numbers that appear
                   in the matrix from x
```

---

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 22 bytes

```
{((*>^/^\+\2#,x-)')_x}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJx1kF0OwiAMgN85RZclG8wtBRzGEGe8h4jhZWfATO8uxZ85jQmhpV/7NWG0E+fN3qN3K6fLNnaiFud4Y2y003RFDANa3QTLY3cRXt7QHuOJGoirXRl88MQTXjDO1dBhWXunuG6Ey+Lym807X2hBOpGVTxYPlRpWiHUYnK0fS9G+2a80o6rAXylFS3NVLP7M/f0XUKBh/YrQ5yxFMDkzoCRoCb18PjepMHcTNTrd1DTXDWxBrUEnU//RbBiyVrNCsrZnC/fb/PCRq6BzB9ykakw=)

I think this idea is not touched well yet (or at least not explained well in other answers).

The idea here is: given an element E of list X, E is to be removed from the result if:

- there exists two other elements E2 and E3 of X such that E2 = (E + E3)/2
- ⇔ E, E2, E3 forms an arithmetic progression
- ⇔ E2 = E + k, E3 = E + 2k for some nonzero k
- ⇔ X-E (elementwise) contains k and 2k for some nonzero k

```
{((*>^/^\+\2#,x-)')_x}
{((             )')_x}  apply to each element E and keep those that gives 0
              x-    L = X-E
         +\2#,      (L, 2L)
     ^/^\           set intersection of L and 2L
   *>      first of grade down (index of max)
           all k's (including zero) are found in increasing order;
           index of max is nonzero iff there exist some nonzero k's
```

Comment: Does the first solution need the `(...)^'0`? Or can the answer just be `{x^/x+x-\:x}`

Comment: @coltim Zeros should be eliminated, otherwise the elements of x will appear in the matrix and the result is always empty.

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>10</s> 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ʒ+;Ãg
```

Byte-count halved thanks to *@Steffan* by porting [*@UnrelatedString*'s Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/249019/52210).

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//1CRt68PN6f//RxvqKBjpKBjrKJjoKBga6CiYGoFoIMPIwCAWAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfaXLoZX/T006tM6lSNv6cHP6/1qd/9HRhjpGOsaxOhBaxwTMAtI6pmCWqY6hgY6RgY6JAZRrBhRAqAbJmhoCSZAihLipjoWOobGOEdAkk9hYAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
ʒ      # Filter the (implicit) input-list by:
 +     #  Add the current value to each in the (implicit) input-list
  ;    #  Halve each
   Ã   #  Only keep those values from the (implicit) input-list
    g  #  Pop and push the length to get the amount of remaining values
       #  (only 1 is truthy in 05AB1E)
       # (after which the filtered result is output implicitly)
```

Comment: Porting the Jelly answer is [5 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//1CRt68PN6f//RxvqKBjpKBjrKJjoKBga6CiYGoFoIMPIwCAWAA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org), 39 bytes

```
f a=[x|x<-a,[1]==[1|z<-a,elem(2*z-x)a]]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ8GCpaUlaboWN9XTFBJtoytqKmx0E3WiDWNtbaMNa6pAnNSc1FwNI60q3QrNxNhYqPLO3MTMPAVbhZR8LgWFgqLMvBIFFYU0hWhDHWMdEx3TWHRRUx0zHUMDDGEFIx0FYx0FEx0FQwMdBVMjEA1kGBngVGqqo2ABVAVkGQHFjE2gDoL5AwA)

ovs and Wheat Wizard each saved a byte. Thanks!

Comment: [39 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ8GCpaUlaboWN9XTFBJtoytqKmx0E3WiDWNtbaMNa6pAnNSc1FwNI60q3QrNxNhYqPLO3MTMPAVbhZR8LgWFgqLMvBIFFYU0hWhDHWMdEx3TWHRRUx0zHUMDDGEFIx0FYx0FEx0FQwMdBVMjEA1kGBngVGqqo2ABVAVkGQHFjE2gDoL5AwA)

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 50 bytes

```javascript
a=>a.filter(x=>!a.some(y=>x-y&&a.includes(y*2-x)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY5BDsIgEEX3ngI3DRhKWizGDVzEuJi01NQgmFINnB5Bt7WLyUzyXv78O7zB9/P0XGrrBp1GmUAqYONkFj3jINUemHcPjaNUoY5VBWyyvXkN2uN44HUghKTeWe@MZsbd8IgvLUWcouOVkN06oahbh4VQJNahoKhtckCervmrnIq1@foXI3jZ37xNPUees5kvXgqW4ukD)

#### Commented

```javascript
a =>            // a[] = input
a.filter(x =>   // for each value x in a[]:
  !a.some(y =>  //   test whether there is a value y in a[]:
    x - y &&    //     which is not equal to x
    a.includes( //     and is the average of x and
      y * 2 - x //     another value 2y - x that exists in a[]
    )           //
  )             //   end of some()
)               // end of filter()
```

Answer (score 4):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 20 bytes

```
{x^/a*~=#a:-x-\:2*x}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs6quiNNP1KqzVU600q3QjbEy0qqo5eJKUzBUMFIwhtEKJmAWkFYwBbNMFQwNFIwMFEwMoFwzoABCNUjW1AhIghQhxE0VLBQMjRWMgCaZAABf3xgV)

Switched to @Jonah's approach.

-1 byte thanks  to @ovs!

### Explanation

Input is *x*.

- `a:-x-\:2*x` subtraction table of 2*x* - *x* stored as `a`
- `a*~=#` multiply *a* by inverse of eye of *a* (i.e. zero out *a*'s diagonals)
- `x^/` remove table elements from *x*

Comment: A assignment is shorter than the lambda: `{x^/a*~=#a:(2*x)-\:x}`

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <s>9</s> 7 bytes

```
'?+½?↔₃
```

[Try it Online](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCInPyvCvT/ihpTigoMiLCIiLCJbMSwgMiwgMywgNCwgMTAsIDUyLCAxMDAsIDIwMF0iXQ==) or [verify all test cases](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJhUGoiLCJ2aMabwqMiLCInwqUrwr3CpeKGlOKCgyIsIjs7wqhad0o7Osabw7figbxg4p2M4pyFYGk7wqhaJMO3JF9cImAgPT4gYGpcXCBKcCIsIlsxLCAyLCAzXSwgWzJdXG5bMSwgMiwgMywgNF0sIFtdXG5bMSwgMywgNCwgNV0sIFs0XVxuWzEsIDUsIDEwLCAyMCwgNDBdLCBbMSwgNSwgMTAsIDIwLCA0MF1cblsxLCA1LCA2LCAxMF0sIFsxLCA1LCA2LCAxMF1cblsxLCAyLCAzLCA0LCAxMCwgNTIsIDEwMCwgMjAwXSwgWzEwLCA1MiwgMjAwXVxuWzEsIDIsIDMsIDUsIDgsIDEzLCAyMSwgMzRdLCBbXSJd).

*-2 bytes by porting Unrelated String's Jelly answer*

### How?

```
'?+½?↔₃
'       # Filter for:
 ?+     #  Add the input (vectorizes)
   ½    #  Halve each
    ?↔  #  Remove elements that are not in the input
      ₃ #  Is the length equal to 1?
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 52 bytes

```scala
s=>s.filter(i=>s.forall(j=>i==j|s.forall(_*2!=i+j)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZHBTsMwDIbvewpv2qEBD21di9BEKnHggDhMGuKEEMq2FKUKXWmyCQn27MVJuzLKuESO/8@/LdushBbVZpnJlYXHXOxkKV6lWGppQH5Yma8N3BQFfPZ6AGuZQjqDB/n@dJfbZ@DJUVwZnpiLVGkry0D5eFMKrYOMJ4rz7KtNvJyFfa7OM8ZYBbATmjqJt8K15M4woFYAgYsmGOIUY4Y@HzKGHe1/BaNG60gktIZRR4txMsZwjNG4AX6luuwlSUec/54YwxnEIb3Ohwq85FPu@7cgxiucTDGkUaOaZowY5i5AG6RT@AKVF1uLtLqCTifXDK5H7R49sdlaImilac06k31TXZQqtzqvNw2gUggOOP@xbFQAM5jfwwyG3gdGCQxretAQUht5BN8uFvPFKR76HIYH@7rYT9XbV98)

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>12</s> 10 bytes

```
f(εn¹Mo½+¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P03j3Na8Qzt98w/t1T608////9GGOkY6xjomOoYGOqZGQNJAx8jAIBYA)

```
f(          )  # filter the input to keep only elements that satisfy:
         ½+    # half the sum  
       Mo  ¹   # with each other element of the input 
    ε          # has only 1 element
     n¹        # shared with any elements of the input
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/)

### 58 bytes with unordered sets

*Thanx to [Jitse](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/87681/jitse)!*

```python
lambda l:{*l}-{a for a in l for b in{*l}-{a}if(a+b)/2in l}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY3RCsIgFIav6ynOpZbR5jRi0JMsL5SQBHNjeBPDZzfPMmIX4nfO9/@c6R2fY@iyvd2z1y/z0OD75eDTadFgxxk0uAB@RVOwquQs0UdDzxxtyqgjJoehZcAZdIrBDxmIOiEykHWSDNqmRMoTzX93wfW2/g1Kjv/a2PpSuhZViOMRoVS/302zC5FYEinNHw)

### <s>62</s> 61 bytes with ordered lists

```python
lambda l:[a for a in l if{(a+b)/2in l for b in{*l}-{a}}=={0}]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY3NCsMgEITP7VPsUVtLjfmhBHwS60Ep0oBNQvBSxGe3bppSclh2Zr4ddn6H5zTW2cl79uZlHwZ8rwy4aQEDwwgeBheJOVt6FatFYguJJ58u0aQkZeRJZ8wDNpSqGAgGtWbwkwyazaFk0G6uZVDxclKm4f@sw3hf/x62Avfa2PNSuhVUlMAnjdb98TAvwxiII4HS/AE)

Comment: My entry started to look very much like yours, so I suppose it's yours to take. You can save 4 bytes with `lambda a:{*a}-{i for i in a for j in{*a}-{i}if(i+j)/2in a}`

Comment: Nice, but I'm unsure whether returning unordered sets complies with the question. The task is to "remove from the list", on the other hand, the order of items does not matter for the task.

Comment: I think that is a technicality and is therefore allowed by the default I/O-rules.

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 39 bytes

```ruby
->l{l-l.permutation(2).map{|a,b|a*2-b}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6nOkc3R68gtSi3tCSxJDM/T8NIUy83saC6JlEnqSZRy0g3qbb2f4FCWnS0oY6RjnFsLBeUo2Cko2Cso2Cio2BooKNgagSigQwjAwOgmv8A)

Answer (score 3):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 7 bytes (14 nibbles)

```
|$~<<`&*2@+@_
```

```
|$~<<`&*2@+@_
|               # filter
 $              # input list
  ~             # keeping only elements that are falsy for
   <<           #   discard first element of
     `&         #   common elements of
       *2@      #     twice the input list
                #     and
          +@_   #   sum of this element and the input list
```

[image]

---

Works on the basis that if the average of X and Y is Z, then X+Y=2*Z.  So we just remove all Xs whenever there's a Y that when added to it gives twice one of the other elements of the input.

Step-by-step for input of `[1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 52, 100, 200]`:

```
|$              # for each element x in input=[1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 52, 100, 200]
  ~             # keep it if the following function returns an empty list (falsy):
     `&         #   find elements in common between:
       *2@      #      double the input: [2, 4, 6, 8, 20, 104, 200, 400]
                #   and:
          +@_   #      input + x: 
                #         so, when x=1 => [2, 3, 4, 5, 11, 53, 101, 201]
                #               common elements = [2, 4]
                #             when x=10 => [11, 12, 13, 14, 20, 62, 110, 210]
                #               common elements = [20]
   <<           #   and remove the first element:
                #         so, when x=1 => [4] => so won't keep it
                #             when x=10 => [] => so we'll keep it
```

Comment: Can i request a breakdown in more detail of the algorithm you're using to filter? also hi im alive lol

Comment: @thejonymyster Broken-down a bit more now.  Feel free to ask if there's still something that I can explain better...

Comment: aahhhhh that helps a lot, thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ŒcSe¥ƇḤFḟ@
```

A monadic Link that accepts a list of positive integers and yields the filtered list.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opOTg1ENLj7U/3LHE7eGO@Q7///@PNtRRMNJRMNZRMNFRMDTQUTA1AtFAhpGBQSwA)**

#### How?

```
ŒcSe¥ƇḤFḟ@ - Link: list L
Œc         - ordered pairs (L)
      Ḥ    - double (L) (vectorises)
     Ƈ     - filter the pairs keeping those for which:
    ¥      -   last two links as a dyad - f(pair, doubled L)
  S        -     sum (pair)
   e       -     exists in (doubled L)?
       F   - flatten (this list of pairs whose sum is in the doubled L)
         @ - with swapped arguments:
        ḟ  -   filter discard (take L and remove the pair elements)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org) + `math.unicode`, <s>57</s> <s>51</s> 50 bytes

```factor
[| s | s [ s n+v 2 v/n s ∩ length 1 > ] reject ]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XU-7bsJAEOz9FdNHEPvACAUpbURDE6VCFCezJkb22dydLfHq-QcaN0TKJ9Gm5CvYixvbK-1jZnd2tdefWEY21_X98fU5X3y8IZP2e1iqJMrXhEKTtftCJ8rC0K4kFZFBrPfNWEVOa7AhRVqmyUHaJFfmv4k0j2RqMPO8owe2IwIIjHDuoHELOxS2cIjAh_Ax9jvkxNH9LUyFgqMT9LshpghGEHzBnTvfShsPpnexPMHA-ZJdvVQ8XL0qrv8uv0hJbfiLAO9YQdOWX8WqUd4yWWDY1HXd5Cc)

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>12</s> 10 bytes

```
-Qs-L-LydQ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/XzewWNdH16cyJfD//2hDHQVjHQUTHQXTWAA) or [Verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfiv/F83sFjXR9enMiUwUMHW9f//aEMdBSMdBeNYLhhLR8EEwgGxdBRMIRxTHQVDA6ACIDYxgAuZgURRtEKUmRqBaLB6FGmgFgugDJBlBLLAJBYA)

```python
-Qs-L-LydQ
    L     (Q) # Left map over the implicit input with variable `d`:
      L  Q    #   Left map over the input with variable `k`:
     - yd     #     d*2 - k
   -          #   Remove d from the resulting list
  s           # Flatten
-Q            # Remove elements of the resulting list from the input
```

#### 12-byte solutions

```python
fqFf}-yYTQQQ
```

```python
-Qsf}.OT-QT*
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), <s>80</s> 76 bytes

```
f(l)=l[[[(.5k-l)^2.minfork=l[m]+l[(L-m)^2>0]].minform=L]>0]
L=[1...l.length]
```

This is probably a terrible way of doing it, but whatever. Also, the "words" `minfork` and `minform` that appear in the code are very much intentional, though you will quickly see what they actually parse as in the graph links :P.

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xhboevghmj)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hflewhjjth)

Answer (score 2):

## [T-SQL] 111 bytes

```
DELETE FROM T WHERE EXISTS(Select*From T Y Join T Z ON T.ID NOT IN(Y.ID,Z.ID)And Y.ID<>Z.ID And T.N+Y.N=2*Z.ID)
```

Formatted:

```
DELETE FROM T
WHERE EXISTS(
    Select *
    From T as Y
    Join T as Z
        ON T.ID NOT IN(Y.ID, Z.ID)
        And Y.ID <> Z.ID
        And T.N+Y.N = 2*Z.ID)
```

I *could* save one more byte by using the excremental SQL-89 joins, but my soul is worth more than one byte.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with T-SQL, but can you remove the two spaces at `Y.ID, Z.ID) And` to save 2 bytes?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen  Yep, you are correct.

Comment: Can you remove the space before `*` after `Select `?

Comment: @Steffan Yes, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 41 bytes

```
$[a][a--map permutate.by:2a'p[-p\0*2p\1]]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?I0bU8I)

Port of G B's [Ruby answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/249099/97916).

Answer (score 2):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 14\log_{256}(96)\approx \$ 11.52 bytes

```
gz0+2/z0sAqS2<
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhbr0qsMtI30qwyKHQuDjWwgglC5BWuiDXUUjHUUTHQUTGMhYgA)

##### Explanation

```python
g   # Filter:
z0+ # Add input
2/  # Halve each
z0  # Push input again
sAq # Each is in the input?
S2< # Sum is less than 2?
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 16 bytes

```
ĐĐ2*⇹ɐ-ĐŁřĐɐ≠*Ƒ\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AS0A0v9weXT//8SQxJAyKuKHucmQLcSQxYHFmcSQyZDiiaAqxpFc//9bMSwyLDMsNF0)

Port of [Jonah's J answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/248996/116013)

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 32 bytes

```julia
!l=l[l.|>i->sum(i.+l.∈[2l])<2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY5RCsIwDED/d4rsr8M6XN3EDze8gCcY@wisQiVWaaf44QE8pxeZrXEwsFCavLykOd3IYPEYx5Rqail/NmbZ@NtZmHxB@fv1ahV12U514/HiwICx4DT2ZKz2IksgHJQaatB3JHHQA@ZXdF4Lk3H16owdyAqEuoEUGe7Re@2GkEMdWhNt@7EtJCgJ6y6KreqSCUgomTGKuYSKUcmsklCsgh1uueLKH53ETaRzh8H8O@6rVHy/Ayb/RyOY@WHGNqghUnG/adsP)

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 68 bytes

```powershell
($a=$args)|?{$_-notin($a|%{$a-ne($c=$_)|%{$_,$c*(($_+$c)/2-in$a)}})}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lU/RSsMwFH3vV1zGVRJNcKub@FIsFH3wRXF7Eyk1Zm6yNbPJVGj77TVJtyLbHmagNPece07OWalvWeiZXCy4UIVscBqVDcEswqx417S6KTHluTLz3ILVSYkZzyVBEWFK3ZgyFGeEYHqOgl6EfJ5jRuua1k0dBDEJwB4GMYnJgEHI4JK6KaR0n2Ew9OQu5wgGI88Nd8kRg0Hf6u037PuVPXBfceX4P8vtfDhSazUK3d97boQb0M0Hhdb22mrsLXQdumoUKrhTxW0mZvzh9UMKA6XXo5HaMED5s7KgfIMIMG2ZQur1wljgFKcQuz2PPz@Ok7U2atn6vMStkTvjtRBSa3@PgGwdKhirwmzfrSBR@ZcszETxe61y4IlaruyqpsDlp5V1WY4Wdgl6ExsTkkzLnmviQh/t0pk8tbE3Nf7bwtvUQd38Ag)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 16 bytes

```
ＩΦθ¬⊙θ∧⁻κμ№⊗θ⁺ιλ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYvBCoMwEER/ZY8rbCGm9tSTWLy1eBcPqQoN3SYYk4Jfv0ZwLvN4w4wfE0ZvWKQL1kVszBqxtRzngAvBy0es3XZg7SZ8WpdW/BL8CoLGp3x4@PTmecIlm47zagm4OHMX6fuSQBNcCSqCUhHc9NEZtFLDIJc/7w) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
  θ                 Input list
 Φ                  Filtered where
     θ              Input list
   ¬⊙               No elements satisfy
       ⁻κμ          Indices differ
      ∧             Logical And
            θ       Input list
           ⊗        Doubled
          №         Does not contain
             ⁺ιλ    Sum of current elements
Ｉ                   Cast to string
                    Implicitly print
```

Comment: @thejonymyster Sorry, I put it on the wrong line, it should be on the "Cast to string" line... thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 26 bytes

```
Js12CB:U_f{avg1j~[}g1jFL\\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/V@tZGunZG2tG1uUqFmS8t@r2NDI2ckqND6tOrEs3TCrLroWSLr5xMT8rw3P@R9tqKNgpKNgHKtga6cQbRTLBRPQUTCBiMUqgMVAAjoKphAxE4g6Ux0FQwOgciA2MYDIYIjCFJqBRJHVQASQ7YPoMzUC0WADYOqhoiABJPVAMyyASoEsI5D7YM4FAA)

Takes input as block of doubles

```
J          # Duplicate
s1         # Store as 1
2CB        # Combinations of length 2
:U_        # Filter for unique (guaranteed safe by no dups)
f{avg1j~[} # Filter for average contained in original list (1)
g1         # Get 1
j          # Reorder stack
FL         # Flatten
\\         # Remove elements contained in (1) also in averages
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org), 67 bytes

```
f a=[z|z<-a,not$elem z[x|x<-a,y<-a,x/=y,even$x+y,div(x+y)2`elem`a]]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ8GCpaUlaboWN53TFBJto6tqqmx0E3Xy8ktUUnNScxWqoitqKkAilSCiQt-2Uie1LDVPpUK7Uicls0wDSGsaJYCUJiTGxkKMgpoIMxkA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 75 bytes

```sh
for x;for y;((s=x+y,s%2||x==y))||a+=(${=${(M)@:#$[s/2]}:+$x $y})
<<<${@:|a}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZDBbsIwEETv/oqpcNUEkAoBpAqIxKGH9tBjTxVSXLIBqyRGsQNJCd@e2gGKVPXitXbXM/P8rTdN4vlek6gc5cyd1czzdFj2qr6@D@q6DMPK9@ta9EKPH0N@9N78xbTDP/RjsDxNe7wEr04@m8/n/LiY1uLU@IwlGCLA@FJH13rp2IpJe5tgOEAwwHhwW3GtSWBPN7n1J3jCcITAPh8zRqU0jHXwrEhnDwYHlX/1IbIYZkPISWiV4bCpsFLFNsYnodCUFFs4xLXaJjJbT9l/1GloyW7sdX3HFx/eq8/T5e8/OGbf2b9QToh4GkFqULmzASiGtXYpuruc9lIVuou92BYElYCnNos1JMTKRmj3RC7NJiUjV2cJLVVmtd@1WziLZ9qQiJ1AtItazKi/C@3kL55MUKkCGdkYRkGLPbUe1yiQhnJhrEPzAw)

Not as compact as I was expecting...

```sh
for x;for y   # for $x, $y in the Cartesian product of the list with itself
    ((s=x+y,s%2||x==y)) ||          # test if the sum is odd or x == y. If not,
    a+=(${=${(M)@:#$[s/2]}:+$x $y})
#          ${(M)@:#$[s/2]}          # substitute the average if found in $@
#       ${                :+$x $y}  # if non-empty, substitute "$x $y"
#   a+=(${=                      }) # split on spaces and add it to $a

<<<${@:|a}                          # set difference
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python](https://www.python.org) + NumPy, 50 bytes

```
lambda a:a[((a+[[a]]).T==a+a[:,1>0]).sum((0,1))<2]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VY5BCsIwEEX3PcUsExxLkrZSivUU7mIWI1Is2DTEFuxZ3BRE8Urexth24-q9_z8Dc3-5oTu3dnxU5eHZd9U6_6gLNccTARWkGaOV1mQMj_dlSSvSBcqdCPHaN4wJlJxvlVku33XjWt-B7Rs3AF3BuqhqPdwAagtaosLE4ExMJwvEbLIMpUAlMBVThAxhgyCXpBAShPRXhEn9GESJvzmc5GEJpkKXpKaIwPnadqxi1sXkPQ3sxjmf_x3HmV8)

Straightforward masking with a few tricks to shorten the required indexing operations without having to explicitly import numpy.

##### How?

Construct 3d table of *z,y,x* each running through the input list *a*. Each cell is True if *2z=y+x* and False otherwise. Fixing *x=a* count solutions *z,y*. If *a* is not part of an averaging pair there is only solution *z=a,y=a*, otherwise there are more. Use boolean indexing to filter *a* accordingly.

`(a+[[a]]).T` is a shorter surrogate for `2*a[:,None,None]` and `a[:,1>0]` is shorter than the more natural `a[:,None]`.